# Convert.ToDouble non-numeric string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to extract the number out of a string that might contain non-numeric characters

I'm thinking `Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Replace(data[i].ToString(), @"ANSWER HERE", ""));`

Example string: `"wd123.321dw"`
Want to get 123.321 out of that.

Also for negatives: `"we-123.321ew"` for -123.321

Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
        string n = "wd123.321dw";
        var regNumber = new Regex(@"\-?\d+\.?\d+");

        var match = regNumber.Match(n);
        if ( match.Success )
        {
            double d;
            if ( Double.TryParse(match.Value, out d) )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number is: {0}",d);
            }
        }
```

Comment: got to say I'm blown away by the responses. Haven't stackOverflown for a while, but grinning now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
double d_val = Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Replace(data[i].ToString(), @"[^0-9\.\-]", ""));
```

Comment: didn't work for negatives. I know that wasn't in my question by the time you answered it, responses come in from SO before I can think straight!!

Comment: @Nick - Thats ok, I've updated to include the literal '-'.  This obviously isnt as nice as driis's solution, since his will match only valid numeric formats.

Comment: going to check performance - if yours is significantly faster, it might have to be the method I use!

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your regular expression:

```
"0+" + Regex.Escape(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator) + "0+"
```

This will use the decimal separator of your current regional settings from Windows.