# Separating some signs from other signs in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

Trying To reprase I  want to split "("  ")"  "&&"  "||"
from my string

my original question:
[Separating numbers from other signs in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267592/separating-numbers-from-other-signs-in-a-string)
I use this example

```
string text = "(54&&1)||15";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\(|\)|&&|\|\||\d+");
Match match = pattern.Match(text);
while (match.Success)
{
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

my problem is that I don't always get a proper string with only numbers and the signs
I might get a wierd string like:

```
0ò8F&|&&booBl||aBla
```

I want it to be seperated to

```
0ò8F&| && booBl || aBla
```

Comment: What logic is behind your input -> output? I can't really see how it should be splitted.

Comment: I've run into similar issues before. You might find this post useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090086/convert-todouble-non-numeric-string/4090160#4090160

Comment: Can you please post your code you are using to split your string .

Comment: That string is not valid according to your specification in the other question (you list && but not &). Could you explain why you expect/want 1&2 to be returned as a single unit?

Comment: I am not at all clear what you are asking.  Is the logic defined in you other question?

Comment: @tom @ Nick @ shalini @ chris @ scruffy
I have rephrased.
the idea is that "(" ")" "&&" "||" signs in the string will be seperated from the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working is that, assuming you are using the regular expression provided by Jon Skeet in your accepted answer, you are not looking for that formulation in your string. The regex given was:

```
\(|\)|&&|\|\||\d+
```

this looks for:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
  \(                       '('
 |                        OR
  \)                       ')'
 |                        OR
  &&                       '&&'
 |                        OR
  \|\|                     '||'
 |                        OR
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
```

(courtesy of http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) with slight modifications.

As you can see there is no way this is going to match "&" or "1&2" so if you want it to you need to include these values in the regular expression.

This regex relies on your original statement:

> I got a string that contains:
>
> "("  ")"  "&&"  "||"
>
> and numbers (0 to 99999).

The single `&` in your string that is failing doesn't match the above. Is it the case in fact that you can have the above four string tokens and then any other text or are there still limitations like numbers and optional single `&`? If so then this is actually a different problem from the original...

If you wish to use those four things as delimiters on arbitrary text then Regex.Split may be the way forward (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx).

```
string[] results = Regex.Split(@"(54&1&1)||15", @"(\()|(\))|(&&)|(\|\|)");
```

The above should split the first string by the four specified delimiters ("("  ")"  "&&"  "||") and ouptut all the split strings and the delimiters themselves. One issue you may have with this is that if two delimiters are adjacent then you will get an empty value in the array that you will need to take into account.

The results of the above are:

```
0 - 
1 - (
2 - 54&1&1
3 - )
4 -  
5 - ||
6 - 15
```

Also this will not work on .NET 1.0 or 1.1 but I hope that won't be a problem.

It should be noted that the regular expression has been changed slightly to enclose all the captures in brackets to make them capturing groups and to remove the \d+ group which was just used for anything that wasn't the delimiters.

To remove the blank entries from the array all you need is a line of code like:

```
results = results.Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Of course you can leave it as an IEnumberable or similar if you don't actually need it as an array.

Comment: thank you for the useful link. it was added to my favorites.
what would i need to write to get any sign that isn't in the list? instead of just digits?
and yes I know it falls under a diffrent problem this why I opened a new question

Comment: @Nahum: I've updated my answer to use a slightly different technique that should mostly do what you want.

Comment: @ hi chris 15&&(3||4) fails
it return empty strings in the middle

Comment: @Nahum: it doesn't fail, it just has additional empty strings as I noted it would in my response (see the example I put in the answer for example). All you need to do is when processing the array to strip it out. I'll add that in though for you - I had jsut assumed that you could deal with that yourself.

Comment: you are right i didn't see your comment and feared additional side effects i didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
   List<string> sList = new List<string>();
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\(|\)|&&|\|\||\d+");
    Match match = pattern.Match(text);
    while (match.Success)
    {
        sList.Add(match.Value);
        //Console.WriteLine(text2[nCounter]);
        match = match.NextMatch();

    }string text = "(54&&1)||15";
```

**sList** contain your desired output

Comment: Does this do anything except put the strings into a List rather than output them to console? The problem is that the regular expression isn't matching properly...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the answer I gave to your original question?

See: [Separating numbers from other signs in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267592/separating-numbers-from-other-signs-in-a-string/7267762#7267762)

It solves your problem.

```
var operators = new [] { "(", ")", "&&", "||", };

Func<string, IEnumerable<string>> operatorSplit = t =>
{
    Func<string, string, IEnumerable<string>> inner = null;
    inner = (p, x) =>
    {
        if (x.Length == 0)
        {
            return new [] { p, };
        }
        else
        {
            var op = operators.FirstOrDefault(o => x.StartsWith(o));
            if (op != null)
            {
                return (new [] { p, op }).Concat(inner("", x.Substring(op.Length)));
            }
            else
            {
                return inner(p + x.Substring(0, 1), x.Substring(1));
            }
        }
    };
    return inner("", t).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
};

var list = operatorSplit("0ò8F&|&&booBl||aBla").ToList();
```

Result: `{ "0ò8F&|", "&&", "booBl", "||", "aBla" }`

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are asking:

```
@"\(|\)|&&|\|\||.+?(?=\(|\)|&&|\|\||$)"
```

It substitutes the `\d+` character set in your previous pattern with `.+?(?=\(|\)|&&|\|\||$)` which uses a positive lookahead to instruct the engine to capture everything up to, but not including, your operator tokens.